# Swift - better way for Map Annotations

Tags: dictionary, swift, annotations

Hey i m currently working on a small app but my memory usage is ways to high.
The App got about 200 Map Annotations, these been added like

```
    //Number: 1 Airport: Lukla  - Mount Everest
    let location1:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(AirportLat[1], AirportLong[1])
    let info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
    info1.coordinate = location1
    info1.title = AirportTitle[1]
    info1.imageName = AirportimageName[1]
    Map.addAnnotation(info1)

    //Number: 2 Airport: Helgoland 
    let location2:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(AirportLat[2], AirportLong[2])
    let info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
    info2.coordinate = location2
    info2.title = AirportTitle[2]
    info2.imageName = AirportimageName[2]
    Map.addAnnotation(info2)

    //Number: 3 Airport: Aspen 
    let location3:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(AirportLat[3], AirportLong[3])
    let info3 = CustomPointAnnotation()
    info3.coordinate = location3
    info3.title = AirportTitle[3]
    info3.imageName = AirportimageName[3]
    Map.addAnnotation(info3)
```

From me, so i got some arrays but creating each annotation by it own (but all "arrays just count up one by one") i m sure there is a better way to do this, could anyone give me some tipps how to reduce this and maybe use a for/while for this? :( i don't get any working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate one of the array and then create an array of annotations. Then, you could add all the annotations at once to the map view.

```
var allAnnotations =  [CustomPointAnnotation]()
for (index, value) in enumerate(AirportLat){
  let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
  annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(AirportLat[index], AirportLong[index])
  annotation.title = AirportTitle[index]
  annotation.imageName = AirportimageName[index]
  allAnnotations += [annotation]
}   

Map.addAnnotations(allAnnotations)
```

Comment: thanks @insane-36 :) damn that easy :) i m a idiot :)